# WPF MenuItem apply style to boxed header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu

I'm currently trying to apply styling to my menuItem. I had to center it's header inside the control, and the only way to it that I had found is this:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="About" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Now, I am trying to apply styles, but I can't seem to manage to bind the textboxes' text from style to the actual xaml value.

My style:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemBaseStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a99f3" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem.Header>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                                </MenuItem.Header>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

TemplateBinding is just one of the approaches I tried, though none worked even remotely close.

**EDIT - FULL XAML ON REQUEST:**

```
<Window x:Class="DownloadManager.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DownloadManager"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:DesignInControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000" Background="#22282a" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Grid>
            <controls:CircularProgressBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,10" SegmentColor="#ffcd22" StrokeThickness="5" Percentage="100" Radius="80" Grid.ZIndex="0"/>
            <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,10" Width="170" Height="170">
                <TextBlock FontSize="60" Text="10%" FontFamily="simplifica" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Image x:Name="noshare_png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-8,10" Source="noshare.png" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            <Border Width="210" Height="100" Margin="97,10,665,540">
                <TextBlock Text="NoShare" FontSize="85" FontFamily="simplifica" Foreground="#ffcd22" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Menu x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="352,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" FontFamily="simplifica" FontSize="30">
                <MenuItem Height="100" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="File"/>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Height="100" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Settings"/>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Height="100" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="About"/>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why are you placing a MenuItem inside a MenuItem template?

Comment: If I dont, there won't really be an acutal menuitem in place when I attach the styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MenuItem.HeaderTemplate`.

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemBaseStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a99f3" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

#### Updated: Combined your style with the original solution.

Comment: If I use this alongside my style from question, it seems as if yours gets overriden. When I use it as the only setter in style, the text changes to: `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock`

Comment: Just combine the two styles. Don't define your own template for the whole MenuItem, unless you really need to. MenuItem's original template is way more complicated, with Popup defined etc.

Comment: One thing: I'm still getting `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock` as the header's text.

Comment: You need to post your full code. Something is messing up your `Text="{Binding}"` binding.

Comment: You can just use `<MenuItem Height="100" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}" Header="File" />`. The whole point of doing this is so that you don't need to keep writing that `<MenuItem.Header>` thing for every menuitem, right?

Comment: Ooooooooh. You got me there. Works perfect now. Thanks